# Dimension of solutions of EDP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dimension-theory-analysis

I heard that the manifold consisting of solutions of a given PDEs is of infinite dimension.

Is this statement true for all PDEs ?

Could we write a PDE as infinite ODEs and in that case, the statement makes sense ?

---

Here is a precise context.

We define an optimal control problem as
$$
\underset{u(.)}{ \min } \; C(u),\quad
\dot q = f(q,u), \quad q(t) \in M
$$
in that case $M$ is of finite dimension because we have an ODE but if we replace this ODE to a PDE, $M$ is of infinite dimension.

Comment: Well, given the fact that there are PDEs without any solutions, I'd say the answer is no. But for typical PDEs encountered in real-world problems, the answer is yes, since one typically requires a *function* (initial and/or boundary value) to specify the solution.

Comment: Fair point. So there is no classification of PDEs regarding the dimension of the solutions ?

If we consider the wave equation in $(t,x)$ variables, any solution can be written as $l(x-ct)+r(x+ct)$ for arbitrary functions $l$ and $r$. In that case, it is of infinite dimension. But are there some results about such classification ?

Comment: ok indeed in the hypotheses of Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem, a function $\phi$ is given to initialise the problem and we obtain then a unique solution.
So there should be a linear map between the set of initial functions $\phi$ and the set of solutions of the PDE.

Comment: Not linear … there are lots of nonlinear PDEs! Which is why the concept of manifold enters, rather than just a space of solutions. Also, Cauchy–Kowalevskaya is really about *analytic* solutions with analytic initial values, which really is a different kettle of fish than what one usually encounters in real-world problems.

Comment: so there is no structure-preserving of such map in the general case ? so we cannot conclude about the infinite dimension of the solutions ?

Comment: In well-posed problems the solution is at least continuously dependent on the data. So yes, I'd say that gives you an infinite-dimensional manifold of solutions, at least heuristically. But to make that statement rigorous is harder, and outside my field of expertise, so I can't be more specific. Sorry.